# How to align bootstrap div horizontally on the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

Hi Please look at the code:-

```
   <form runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> Quick Shortcuts</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <br/>Apps</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> <br/>Bookmarks</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> <br/>Reports</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> <br/>Comments</a>


                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <br/>Users</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> <br/>Notes</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> <br/>Photos</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> <br/>Tags</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

The output i am getting is like this:-https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3C0B.png
It is on the right side of the page. I want it to be on horizontally centered and responsive too.

Please help..

Comment: is changing your col-md-6 class an option? Changing <div class="col-md-6"> to <div class="col-md-12"> works for me locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with col-md-offset-*, may be this will help u

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> Quick Shortcuts</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <br/>Apps</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> <br/>Bookmarks</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> <br/>Reports</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> <br/>Comments</a>


                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <br/>Users</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> <br/>Notes</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> <br/>Photos</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> <br/>Tags</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You saved me!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a closing tag missing in your code.

To center you add `mx-auto` to your column like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> Quick Shortcuts</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <br/>Apps</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> <br/>Bookmarks</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> <br/>Reports</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> <br/>Comments</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <br/>Users</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> <br/>Notes</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> <br/>Photos</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> <br/>Tags</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

P.S. You seem to be using Bootstrap 3 but your tag indicates Bootstrap 4.